# How to set Ruby on Rails user profile to user's local time zone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, timezone

In my Rails 3 application I have this:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  attr_accessible :time_zone

  validates_inclusion_of :time_zone, in: ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map(&:name)

  before_create :set_defaults

  private

  def set_defaults
    self.time_zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone["London"]
  end

end
```

How can I make it default to the current user's **system time** when the user first signs up?

Right now, I have `self.time_zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone["London"]`, as you can see. But that is static and doesn't even get past the validation method I defined above.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your validation is checking that `:time_zone` is in the list of TimeZone *names*, but you're assigning an actual TimeZone object. Try:

```
def set_defaults
  self.time_zone = "London"
end
```

And to default to the current system's timezone:

```
def set_defaults
  self.time_zone = (Thread.current[:time_zone] || Time.zone_default).name
end
```

Comment: Thank you. This does seem to make sense but the problem is this is seemingly not accepted by my validation method. Normally, a new profile will be created automatically with any new user. But when trying any of your code or my code above, I get a `profile is nil` error.

Comment: Interesting. Can you try running `Profile.create!` in your `rails console` to see the validation errors?

Comment: Now it works. The error I got was not related to this class. The code you provided works like a charm. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Gem which makes this very easy.

[Detect Timezone Rails](https://github.com/scottwater/detect_timezone_rails)

Other options include

- Manually set by user (Accurate, but who wants to do it)
- Set from phone number, or zip code (These may be optional fields, my phone number is not from my time zone)
- Set from IP Address (Proxies)

**From the Manual**

In your Gemfile:

```
gem 'detect_timezone_rails'
```

Require detect_timezone and jquery.detect_timezone in your Javascript manifest (i.e. application.js)

```
//= require detect_timezone
//= require jquery.detect_timezone
```

Then some where else, wire it up using the plugin (remember to require jquery as well for the plugin)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#your_input_id').set_timezone(); 
});
```

If you are using the standard rails form helpers to generate a timezone select, you may pass the
`format` option when calling `set_timezone`, to return only the city name:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#your_input_id').set_timezone({format: 'city'});
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I went with Ash's solution this time because I was looking for a pure Ruby solution. I will keep the jQuery version in mind for my next project, though.

Answer (score 0):

One Idea

Include `gem 'timezone'` in **Gemfile**

After registration update user's timezone from address or zipcode.

After login convert time to `user_time.in_time_zone('timezone')`